# Keras custom loss using multiple input

Tags: keras

I have a model in keras with a custom loss. this loss is calculated using actual and predicted labels(or values) and **is also based on some input value**.

(an example would be to define loss based on reward or advantage as in a policy gradient method in reinforcement learning context )

example code:
note: the input value used in loss calculation is named 'in2' and variable is `input_2`

```
input_1=keras.layers.Input(...,name="in1")
output= keras.layers.Dense(...)(input_1)

input_2=keras.layers.Input(...,name="in2")
def loss_func(y_true,y_pred):
    # some custom loss i define based on input_2
    loss = keras.layers.Dense(..)(input_2) 
    return loss

my_model=keras.Model(inputs=[input_1,input_2],outputs=output)
my_model.compile(...,loss=loss_func,)
```

Now the problem is that when I want to just predict an output, I have to give a dummy input for the unused `input_2`. The `input_2` is only used for computing the loss and it is not used for computing the model output. but when i use this code, an error ocures for not providing 'in2':

```
# this throws error for not providing input value for 'in2'
my_model.predict({'in1':some_value})
```

so I have to provide some dummy value for `in2` so the model outputs its value, although it does not use the `in2` value provided. note that providing None value does not work either. I thought this functionality is implemented inside keras.

or **maybe I am doing it the wrong way? if yes, what is the appropriate way?**

idea:
An idea came to my mind was that maybe we can define two models. one model for training and another for predicting:

```
my_model_for_training = keras.Model(inputs=[input_1,input_2],outputs=output)
my_model_for_predicting = keras.Model(inputs=[input_1],outputs=output)
```

and when I want to predict, I just use the second model which does not require the input_2 (or `in2`) as in example. both models share the same layers so when train the first model, the weights are updated for both models as explained in docs [(section: Shared layers)](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/). is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

When you are in the inference phase, there is no loss to be calculated unless you are using a validation set to fine tune your model on.
Using two models with shared layers in between is fine yet I suggest to start training the model and don't waste your time writing perfect code.